# Can't seem to cast from NSString* to CFString* using ARC

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, cfstring

I am using the following code to obtain a file's file type in Objective-C (Mac OS X Cocoa Application):

```
NSString *kind = nil;
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
LSCopyKindStringForURL((CFURLRef)url, (CFStringRef*)&kind);
return kind ? kind : @"";
```

However, the only error being produced is on the following line:

```
LSCopyKindStringForURL((CFURLRef)url, (CFStringRef*)&kind);
```

Saying:

> C-style cast from 'NSString *__strong *' to 'CFStringRef *' (aka
>   'const __CFString **') casts away qualifiers

After doing some research, I saw that the `__bridge` keyword is required to make the cast from NSString* to CFStringRef* valid in ARC. So I stuck in the keyword, producing:

```
LSCopyKindStringForURL((CFURLRef)url, (__bridge CFStringRef*)&kind);
```

Now, I am receiving the following error:

> Incompatible types casting 'NSString *__strong *' to 'CFStringRef *'
>   (aka 'const __CFString **') with a __bridge cast

It's starting to drive me crazy... no matter what I seem to try, I just can't make the error go away. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a simple workaround. Use an actual `CFStringRef` variable and cast it when it comes time to return it as an `NSString`:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
CFStringRef kind;
LSCopyKindStringForURL((CFURLRef)url, &kind);
return kind ? CFBridgingRelease(kind) : @"";
```

Comment: I believe your memory management here is incorrect, but you're getting away with it because `LSCopyKindStringForURL` typically returns static strings (which do not *actually* require memory management). I believe what you want here is `return kind ? CFBridgingRelease(kind) : @"";` to pass the `CFStringRef` to ARC for memory management.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to get kind

```
    (NSURL *)path
    NSString *tempKind;
    [path getResourceValue:&tempKind forKey:NSURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey error:nil];
```